# Non-special first page in \documenclass{article}

Tags: header-footer, titles, fancyhdr, article

I'm new to TeX and LaTeX, so I might not explain it all that well.

I'm trying to put pagenumbers on each footer in the form "Page X of XX" using `fancyhdr`. So far I have this:

```
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

This works fine, except on page 1, which just contains "1".

I suppose this is because the first page is a sort of "special page", since it doesn't contain the header as well.

How do I disable this special first page, so that all pages contain both the header and footer?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: You should use `\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}` (note the ``\`` after `\thepage`) -- otherwise a space will be gobbled.

Comment: Or `\cfoot{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you make the first page using `\maketitle` this may execute `\thispagestyle{plain}`. You may either redefine page style `plain` (see the `fancyhdr` manual for this), or simply add `\thispagestyle{fancy}` **after** `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\end{document}
```

BTW: If you're using more versatile [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class `scrartcl` instead of standard class `article`. You may redefine the page style of the page with the in page title head:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand*{\titlepagestyle}{fancy}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

There are more of those page style commands at KOMA-Script, e.g., `\chapterpagestyle` for the page with chapter heading (only `scrbook` and `scrreprt`). Have a look at the KOMA-Script manual for all these commands.

Answer (score 4):

Without saying `\thispagestyle`:

```
...
\pagestyle{fancy}
<customizations related to fancyhdr>
\expandafter\let\csname ps@plain\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname ps@fancy\endcsname
...
\begin{document}
...
\maketitle
```

Comment: Maybe a beginner would understand it a little easier without `\expandafter` and `\csname` using `\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy\makeatother`. I know: beginners ofter do not understand why to use `\makeatletter` but `\expandafter` together with `\endcsname\csname` may be one step to high …

Comment: I don't really understand why I would do this instead of just writing \thispagestyle{fancy} (as suggested). I suppose there are advantages of doing this, however the other way is fine for me right now.

Comment: @Schweinebacke It was just to show a different approach. Definitely not for beginners, I agree. :)

Comment: @AndersHovgaard It was only to show that it's not necessary. This trick may become handy when using the **book** class, where each `\chapter` command issues a `\thispagestyle{plain}` and it would be cumbersome to write every time `\thispagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: @egreg Okay, that makes sense. Perhaps it will be handy at some other time.

Comment: @Schweinebacke `\pagestyle{fancy}` always uses the current values assigned with the `\fancy...` commands, so `\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy` is good as well.

Comment: @egreg: Oh, yes. I'll remove this nonsense comment of mine.

Answer (score 3):

Many packages or styles issue the command `\thispagestyle{plain}` in `\maketitle`, so the first page is indeed "special".  Try to override this with `\thispagestyle{fancy}` on title page.