# How to make Page X of Y in article document class?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to just have a footer with "Page X of Y", but the following only works half the way for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\bfseries \Huge Nothing Else Matters}
\author{my name \thanks{myname@mail.com} \\ { \vspace{-10pt} \normalsize \scshape Institute for Nothing, No University} \vspace*{10pt} }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

**Trouble**

I would like to have the "Page X of Y" on the first page, which currently it only prints "1". And "Page X+1 of Y" to "Page Y of Y" are in the middle of the page, but not centered. It's like we have the page middle and it just write the footer to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and the setting of page styles *after* [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). As reference, see [`geometry`, `fancyhdr`: `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` is not really centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33874/5764).

The page on which `\maketitle` is issued necessarily also issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`. While you do set `\thispagestyle{fancy}`, it's reset by `\maketitle`. Again, placing `\thispagestyle{fancy}` *after* `\maketitle` fixes this. Alternatively, you can issue

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
```

in your preamble. See [Non-special first page in `\documenclass{article}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36994/5764).

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\bfseries \Huge Nothing Else Matters}
\author{my name \thanks{myname@mail.com} \\ { \vspace{-10pt} \normalsize \scshape Institute for Nothing, No University} \vspace*{10pt} }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps recommend `parskip` and `pageslts`?

Answer (score 1):

Move command `\thispagestyle` after `\maketitle`:

```
%\thispagestyle{fancy}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

After creating the titel the moved command can work and change the footer as you want.