# Page X of Y at bottom of Centered

Tags: page-numbering

I have the following code working for page number

```
\documentclass[18pt,letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{}{ 2 }{\vphantom{x}\newpage}
\end{document}
```

This provides my the page numbers at the bottom of page.
I would to just have page x of y at the bottom of the pages.   I am working with existing pdf files with no page numbers.    I merge this file with pdftk and its multistamp feature to the existing pdf file with the created pdf file.

Comment: this can be achieved with the packages `lastpage` and `fancyhdr`, see for example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265861/110842

Comment: How do I make it loop and create a blank page?  The multido loop allows me to loop for the number of pages I need.

Comment: You just need to set it up in the preamble as shown in the linked answer. This sets a new pagestyle, which is then used automatically for all pages.

Comment: I am still not sure how to loop to create say 10 pages with just Just "Page 1 of 10", "Page 2 of 10" etc.   I am using this to apply page numbers to existing pdf files.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

This is the code that work for what I am doing

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=-2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,20}
{\ \newpage}   
\end{document}
```